# Groupings and pivoting

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAyCD.jpg)I am trying to write a code for the scenario.

column a- group - 1-4 , 5-7 , 8-10, 11+ and New (5 groupings)

Amount field, Count field

So, For fiscal year 2020- i got 4 rows except New.

For fiscal year 2019, i got 3 rows except 5-7 and New. [12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYIFU.png)

I have to pivot to get previous year measure and current year measure side by side.

Group Amtcy amtpy

1-4 amout1 Amount2
5-7 amount1 null
8-10 amount1 amount2
11+  amount1 amount2

i tried lag function , however since i have groupings it is not working for py as expected. Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uwUj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbzNv.png)

Comment: can you explain the scenario with sample data and show expected results..?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and not able to format it correctly. Can you help me on this?

Comment: I have added an image. Please check.

Comment: you'd better using text data rather than images, at least for your future questions. Since it will be easier to copy, paste, and manipulate for the people answering your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Conditional Aggregation` by matching the current year and previous calculation by proper use of `sysdate` pseudocolumn :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY') AS "Year",
       "Group",
       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN year = TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY') THEN 
                     amount
                 END),0) AS "Amount",
       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN year = TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY') THEN 
                     count
                 END),0) AS "Count",                 
       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN year = TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY') - 1 THEN 
                     amount
                 END),0) AS "Amount PY",
       NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN year = TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY') - 1 THEN 
                     count
                 END),0) AS "Count PY"                                  
  FROM t
 GROUP BY "Group" 
 ORDER BY TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR("Group",'[^-+]+') )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2bcc6303a63c683595ad0297f56eb8e7)</kbd>

Comment: Sysdate only takes this year. I need for 5 years. If it is 2020 Current year, previous year should be 2019. if it is 2019, It should be 2018 and so on.. How to do that? I should be able to get the data for 4 years in one extract. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, Can you please help me in writing this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64095081/need-help-on-the-case-statement . Please see the link.

Comment: well @AmrithaRaj , you need 11 columns(2020,2019...,2016) but gave me 5 columns(2020,2019), didn't you? Btw, run the demo for sysdate replaced with sysdate-365, this will return the previous year's result. Have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=691895bc6912a53cbcd003372c427529)

Comment: I am sorry. I missed that part.

Comment: Hi Barbaros- I have a question. I pasted a sample data in the excel. However, in the with statement- you hardcoded the values with Union all. I have huge number of records/multiple columns(more than 15) on my data right now.. What is the best way to do that? I need the data in rows. Not the columns.

Comment: No, not hardcoded @AmrithaRaj , it was jsut a representation of the table. Have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2d0aa183d9c410a8c97935f5083f3a3a) alternatively. This is the same with that previous one.

Comment: Hi Barbaros- I am working on group column using the case statement. However, I want to add one more group within this case i.e. 1-10. It should sum the measure values from '1-4' , 5-7' and '8-10' group. What is the best way to do that? case WHEN YEAR_DIFF BETWEEN 1 AND 4 Then '1-4'
WHEN YEAR_DIFF BETWEEN 5 AND 7 Then '5-7'
WHEN YEAR_DIFF BETWEEN 8 AND 10 Then '8-10'
WHEN YEAR_DIFF >=11 THEN '11+'
WHEN YEAR_DIFF IN ('0','-1') THEN 'New'
END

Comment: what do you mean by **YEAR_DIFF** @AmrithaRaj ..  ? I Suppose those were **month** intervals... Since each portion fits within a single year for the rows. Btw, you can edit the function in order to add more question to the current one rather than commenting hre with huge entries ...

Comment: Year difference is a numeric column with the difference of years i.e. 1,2,3,4,5 etc.

Comment: Then you literally need "Year", "Amount", "Count", "Amount PY", "Count PY", "Amount 2018", "Count 2018", "Amount 2017", "Count 2017", "Amount 2016", "Count 2016" , don't you? So, as I said before, you need 11 columns totally, OK? @AmrithaRaj

Comment: Not the columns. I need rows for each year - Say current year is 2020 - the measure should show CY Amount and PY Amount in one row. Say current year is 2019 - the measure should show CY Amount and PY Amount in ANOTHER  row and so on..

Comment: Do you mean that the bottom part(the one with 6 columns) is the data of your current table, and the top part(with 4 columns) is the expected output ..? If so you're looking for unpivot, not pivot @AmrithaRaj

Comment: Top one is how my table is currently. I am doing self join to pull all the Prior year values with the groupings. I am facing issues. Even though I did Left join. I keep getting values as a inner join.Only the year diff values which are matching in PY table are showing up on the result set. Others are showing nulls.Not sure why am i getting nulls for the values. I am not getting side by side values for the respective groups.

Comment: I added one more image at the bottom of my ask. First Image where there are nulls. Thats what I am talking about. Since the year diff values are different. I was doing left join to the same table. I still did not add the group column at this point in my image.